# How do I set uploaded image back to default image when deleted?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple blog app, when I update an article and remove photo I want it to use default photo.
it selects that image on create but when updating it throws an error.

here's my Models.py code.

```
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to="uploads/articles/",
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    default="uploads/articles/noimage.png",
)
```

the error I get when I remove image during update.

```
Error during template rendering
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
<img class='article-img' src="{{article.image.url}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/)
on delete or update or create, please read more about it.

It is like run trigger on model for example when update method happen you can check image field if it empty you can add image to it.

**solution 2**: override **save method** in django model and apply previous condation

**solution 3**: make static field using **@proparty** and check from front end if there is no image .. render this field

**solution 4**: I'm not sure about it but you can check **on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT**

Comment: if I override save method it'd never upload another photo but always default image. which i dont want unless there's no image uploaded or user removed photo.

I am currently getting away with it using second solution. and third one wont work since it's used for relationship fields only.